# Drupal website only in Arabic on English installation 

Tags: 7

I have installed my Drupal in English Language. But i want my all pages to be only in Arabic as of now. English launch will be later. How i do such that all wesbiste content can be only in Arabic and Admin language will be in English.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need the [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module to enable your drupal website for a multilingual setup. It should be no affair to have Arabic as the preliminary language, though you may think about having English as the default language due to some string issues. If you want a website with right-to-left text direction, you'll need a theme which supports this.

A good start to see what's also important can be found in this comprehensive [tutorial](http://drupal-translation.com/content/setup-multilingual-site).

Comment: I have all the modules and everything and i had done the website in 2 languages, Now client requirement is that the site should be in only one language i.e Arabic and they will think of the English release later. So how do i make websites default language to Arabic?

Comment: So you have the site already translated to arabic and just need to make Arabic the default language?

Comment: Have you checked these setting under admin/config/regional/language? http://drupal-translation.com/sites/default/files/language_setup.png

Comment: yup. Yeah i tried that but when i add a content it asks for its translation also.

Comment: I don't know of an automatic way to translate content, if you mean that. You always have to add the translated content itself.

Comment: can you provide a link to the website please

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the default language in i18n to Arabic.

After that you will have to install this module [Admin Langauge](https://drupal.org/project/admin_language)

> This module lets the administrator see all administration pages in her preferred language.
>
> You can use this to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep most of the backend in English (or another language of your choice).